# Update Column with the sequence of primaryKey in Spring boot jpa

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have a table called user table and having the primary key column as Id. Now there is another column employeeid.Now this column value should be generated based on the ID column. Employee Id column should be in the below format.

EE00001 for employee where id column value is 1.
ES00002 for students where id column value is 2.

The goal is to "for employee id i dont need to generate the sequence since sequence is already generating for id column so that i can use it.".
So how can i acheive this in spring boot jpa. Any other ideas for generating employee_id column is also helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way is to save `Employee` twice in one transaction

```java
@Transactional
public void saveEmployee(Employee employee) {
    employeeRepository.save(employee);
    employeeRepository.flush(); // to have id

    employee.setEmployeeId(EmployeeUtils.generateId(employee.getId()));
    employeeRepository.save(employee);
}
```